# CORS is blocking Post, Put and Delete but Get all and Get by Id work fine. React to Springboot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, cors

the console error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9191/api/v1/employee' from origin     'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The Cors have been configured in the backend globally and it works.

Here are 2 endpoints, very standard, except the Post does't work and the Get does:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/employee")
@ResponseBody
public EmployeeDTO createEmployee(EmployeeDTO employee){
    return employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
}

@GetMapping("/employee")
public List<EmployeeDTO> getEmployees(){
    return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
}
```

Comment: *The Cors have been configured in the backend globally and it works* apparently it doesn't

Comment: What `CORS` related configuration has been done on the backend? Can you please post some details about it as well ?

Comment: `reactjs` tags, where is the React code?

Comment: I think the cors works as the gets work fine. Here it is:

Comment: @inkredusk:  
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedHeaders(CorsConfiguration.ALL)
                        .allowedOriginPatterns(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
            }
        };
    }

Comment: has the right annotations over the class and WebMvcConfigurer implemented in the class

Comment: @Aleksandar    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //provides this event
        await axios.post(COURSE_API_URL, userData, axiosConfig).then(res => {
            setUserData({
                email: '',
                pass: '',
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                employeeAddress: '',
                employeePhoneNumber: '56678',
                salaryPA: '5600',
                b2b: 'No',
                team: 'HR',
                departmentId: 102
            })
        }).catch(

Comment: I believe the react is fine as I can see the payload is full of the input and it is merely the error above that I get

Comment: _"GET works, POST doesn't"_ makes me think it might be related to [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) vs [Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests)